# No file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

No matter what I do I can not get this to run from a script. It just keeps erroring out with the message:

> mv: rename item to tempplc: No such file or directory

```
tempplc = '/mnt/Volume_1/USB_DRIVE/'
mvs = []
tvs = []
tds = []

for item in dwnlds:

    result = re.search(r"s\d\de", item, re.I)
    tdsrlt = re.search(r"the.daily.show", item, re.I)

    if result == None:
        if tdsrlt != None:
            tds.append(item)
        else:
            mvs.append(item)
    else:
        tvs.append(item)

os.chdir('/mnt/Data/jails_2/sabnzbd_1/var/db/sabnzbd/Downloads/complete')

for item in tds:
    os.system('mv -v  item tempplc') #<---- PROBLEM LINE
```

No matter what I do I can not get this to run from a script. It just keeps erroring out with the message:

Answer (score 1):

Command `'mv -v  item tempplc'` attempts to move file `'item'` (*sic!*) into the folder `'tempplc'`. Replace the variable names with their values:

```
'mv -v {} {}'.format(item, tempplc)
```